How to add SYSTEM user's access the network shared printer added by administror account?
Network shared Printer Name: "\192.168.0.100\Gprinter GP-3120TL"
In administrator account enter \192.168.0.100 through RUN (win+R), enter the username and password, double-click the printer to automatically download the driver and install it locally.
I run this in php(Apache service default run in SYSTEM user) to check Printer list:
$printers = shell_exec('wmic printer get name');
echo nl2br($printers);

return:
Name
Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Microsoft Print to PDF
Fax

If I run "wmic printer get name" in cmd, return:
Name
Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Microsoft Print to PDF
Fax
\\192.168.0.100\Gprinter GP-3120TL

Add SYSTEM user/group permissions in printer properties-security tab, didn't work.
Add a printer in the printmanagement.msc, didn't work.
Add a printer in gpedit.msc, didn't work.
Change Service-Apache2.4-Login use admininstrator(default is SYSTEM)-WORKING.
WHERE I doing something wrong? Why can't SYSTEM access the network shared printer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
